# JSON Serialization not working properly

Tags: json, swift

I've been learning the basics of JSON and I am trying to read data from a JSON file that I have written. The JSON file looks like this:

```
gradeBoundaries = {
    "Subjects": [ 
        {
        "Title":"Biology HL", 
        "Boundaries": 
            {
            1:[0,15],
            2:[16,27],
            3:[28,39],
            4:[40,52],
            5:[53,64],
            6:[65,77],
            7:[78,100]
            }
        }   

    ]
}
```

The code that I am using to take the data from this file is as follows:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gradeBoundaries", withExtension: "json") {
        do {

            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            do {

                let jsonResult: [([String: String], [String: [Int : [Int]]] )]  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [([String: String], [String: [Int : [Int]]] )]  //the entire object

            } catch {}
        } catch {}
    }
```

When I run the code above, everything works fine until this line:

```
let jsonResult: [([String: String], [String: [Int : [Int]]] )]  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [([String: String], [String: [Int : [Int]]] )]  //the entire object
```

As you can see I am trying to cast `jsonResult` as a fairly complicated data structure. I have tried many others including NSDictionary and Array but none of them seem to make a difference. Since I am so new to JSON I could just be misinterpreting the format of the data, and if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

However, it is indeed nothing to do with the casting, then I am even more lost. This is the way that many SO answers have said to read the data, but it simply does not work for me.

I even tried switching between Data and NSData to no effect. I want to be able to break this data down into smaller pieces, but my program keeps on getting stuck on this line, so I need some help. Thanks!

**EDIT**

Editing the data type to `Any` did not allow the line to execute:

```
let jsonResult: Any  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Any
```

**EDIT**: 31 Dec 2016

Trying to make it work as below was ineffective:

typealias JSONDictionary = [String: Any]

```
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gradeBoundaries", withExtension: "json") {
        do {

            let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: url)

            if let jsonResult: JSONDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? JSONDictionary {

                print("success!")

            }
        } catch {}
    }
```

However, it seems like a really good idea, so I think there must be something seriously wrong about my JSON or I'm doing something really stupid in my code.

**EDIT**

The JSON that I have been using is apparently invalid. I modified it now to be this:

```
{
    "Subjects": [ 
        {
        "Title":"Biology HL", 
        "Boundaries": 
            {
            1:[0,15],
            2:[16,27],
            3:[28,39],
            4:[40,52],
            5:[53,64],
            6:[65,77],
            7:[78,100]
            }
        }   

    ]
}
```

Comment: Please don't parse JSON yourself... there are many great libraries that do that sort of thing for you. Check out my github repository https://github.com/borchero/WebParsing (I prefer my own interface) or simply use the famous SwiftyJSON project (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

Comment: @OliverBorchert Yeah I understand that this is not the easy way by far. But 
I would still like to know how to do it manually.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry The problem is your Subjects array contains dictionary and in that dictionary Title key contains String and Boundaries contains dictionary so you need to specify its type as Any.

Comment: I do think that you cannot do that conversion as you have a tuple in that array (why do you have a tuple anyway??) which is not a valid NSObject type and can thus not be used as object of an NSArray that is actually returned.

Comment: @NiravD Yeah that was one of my early attempts, but the line still does not execute. I just tried it out again just to make sure.

Comment: @OliverBorchert Honestly I was kind of throwing darts in the dark. I am quite confused about how to express my data structure. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also your JSON is invalid. The root object must be unnamed. You can always check at jsonlint.com or similar sites.

Comment: @HAS Thanks for that, I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and feel like an idiot. After using Java and Swift for the longest time, I thought I would leave some comments on my JSON.

The JSON I was *actually* using was this:

```
{
"Subjects": [//[([String: String], [String: [Int : [Int]]] )] 
    {
    "Title":"Biology HL", //[String: String]
    "Boundaries": //[String: [Int: [Int]]]
        {
        "1":[0,15], //[Int: [Int]]
        "2":[16,27],
        "3":[28,39],
        "4":[40,52],
        "5":[53,64],
        "6":[65,77],
        "7":[78,100]
        }
    }   

]
}
```

However, I thought that I would leave the comments out of the SO question because they weren't necessary.

After copying @vadian's suggested JSON my code worked. I then came up with this hypothesis and tried adding a comment to his JSON, and needless to say it didn't work.

So I guess the moral of this story is read up about commenting on code before you actually do it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a message **to all writers of online tutorials**:

## Please stop suggesting the reading option `.mutableContainers` in Swift. It's completely meaningless because mutability is provided for free by assigning the object to a `var`iable.

---

Don't confuse yourself by annotating that weird *snake*-type.

To understand the structure read the hierarchy. `[]` is an array, `{}` a dictionary.

For convenience declare a type alias for a JSON dictionary

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]
```

Then walk through the JSON (assuming the root object is a dictionary):

```
do {
    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:jsonData, options: []) as? JSONDictionary {
        if let subjects = jsonResult["Subjects"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
            for subject in subjects {
                print(subject["Title"] as? String)
                if let boundaries = subject["Boundaries"] as? JSONDictionary {
                    for (key, value) in boundaries {
                        print(key, value)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Regarding the JSON the keys in the `Boundary` dictionary must be strings:

```
{
    "Subjects": [
        {
        "Title":"Biology HL",
        "Boundaries":
            {
            "1":[0,15],
            "2":[16,27],
            "3":[28,39],
            "4":[40,52],
            "5":[53,64],
            "6":[65,77],
            "7":[78,100]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I updated my code to this (at least to the serialization part), but the content inside the first if conditional binding never executes (as before).

Comment: The *JSON* you've posted is not valid. If `Subjects` is the root object remove the first `if` clause after the `JSONSerialization` line.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I already modified the code in my own project but forgot to post the updated JSON here. You can see my edited question now. However, at the time of me posting my previous comment, even with the edited JSON it didn't work. This means that even with your suggestion about removing the second clause, the first line still doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the answer. But the JSON is still not valid. All numeric keys in the `Boundaries` dictionary must be strings (wrapped in double quotes).

Comment: PS: Use the `catch` part not as a necessary evil. At least print the error.

Comment: Great, I didn't realize that, thanks for the comment on the JSON. Also, I just added the print(error) line, and now it is saying "invalid value around character 19" which I assume is referencing the JSON, but the 19th character seems to be the "l" in "title" which doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks so much for your help. I will be posting an answer to my own question, but I would give you rep if I could.